# How to get the graph for $y= \log_{1/a} (x)$ from $y= \log_a (x)$?

Tags: logarithms

I know that it is symmetric the Ox axle, but I can't prove it.

Comment: What is $\;\log_1\;$ and what does $\;\log_1/a(x)\;$ mean?

Comment: What does "symmetric the Ox axle" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $y=\log_a x$ then $x=a^y=\left(\frac 1a\right)^{-y}$. Therefore $\log_{\frac 1a} x=-y$

I always find it easier to write these log equations in terms of exponentials if I am not quite sure what is going on.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a property of logarithm that you need.
$$y = \log_{1/a}(x) = -\log_a (x)$$

Comment: How did you get to that conclusion?

Comment: @Dmytro If $ a^y = x $, then $ (1/a)^{-y} = x $.